# Sequelize - Includes Only Finding One Result

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

**What:**

- **Films** table and a **Credits** table, with a **one-to-many** relation.
- I am running a findAll query on Film and including Credits.

**Problem:** I should be getting ~20 credtis, I am only getting 1.

**Edit Problem:** I set the LIMIT to 20 (I have 28 in the DB). I still get 1 credit per film, however I dont get 20 films... sometimes it is 12, sometimes 16. It is not consistent.

---

**Film Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Film = sequelize.define('Film', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    description: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
  },

  {
    freezeTableName: true
  });


  Film.associate = (models) => {
    Film.hasMany(models.Credit, { foreignKey: 'film_id', as: 'credits' });
  };

  return Film;
};
```

---

**Credits Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Credit = sequelize.define('Credit', {
    film_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  },

  {
    freezeTableName: true
  });


  Credit.associate = (models) => {
    Credit.belongsTo(models.Film, { foreignKey: 'film_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

  return Credit;
};
```

---

**Query**

```
Film.findAll( {
    subQuery: false,
    order: sequelize.literal('rand()'),
    limit: 20,
    include: [
      { model: Credit, as: "credits", required: true, all: true }
    ],
  } )
```

Comment: Is it because of the `limit: 1` property?

Comment: I think you're correct @Cat I'm reading further into it, but something about setting a limit on the findAll is making it behave like this. If I have no limit, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a LIMIT to the outer query of a FindAll also limits the amount of included results.

Whilst confusing at first, this is the intended functionality.